# Oracle JSON_OBJECT NULL ON NULL clause not working

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle18c

I'm trying to get Oracle to produce JSON `null` values on SQL `NULL` data, as follows:

```sql
select 
  json_object(key 'a' value 1, key 'b' value null null on null)   c1, 
  json_object(key 'a' value 1, key 'b' value null absent on null) c2
from dual;
```

Or also:

```sql
select 
  json_object(key 'a' value a, key 'b' value b null on null)   c1, 
  json_object(key 'a' value a, key 'b' value b absent on null) c2
from (
  select 1 a, null b
  from dual
) t;
```

Unfortunately, both queries result in:

```
|C1        |C2        |
|----------|----------|
|{"a":1}   |{"a":1}   |
```

I would have expected this, instead:

```
|C1                 |C2        |
|-------------------|----------|
|{"a":1,"b":null}   |{"a":1}   |
```

What am I missing? I'm using Oracle XE 18c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be a bug on how Oracle handles `JSON_OBJECT` and it will take the parameter from the last `JSON_on_null_clause` in the statement and apply it to all of the `JSON_OBJECT` expressions:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t ( a,b ) AS
  SELECT 1, null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'bb' FROM DUAL;
```

If you do this:

```sql
select json_object(
         KEY 'a' VALUE a,
         KEY 'b' VALUE b null on null
       ) c1,
       json_object(
         KEY 'a' VALUE a,
         KEY 'b' VALUE b absent on null
       ) c2
from   t;
```

Then the output is:

> ```
> C1               | C2              
> :--------------- | :---------------
> {"a":1}          | {"a":1}         
> {"a":2,"b":"bb"} | {"a":2,"b":"bb"}
> ```

If you perform the same query with the expressions reversed:

```sql
select json_object(
         KEY 'a' VALUE a,
         KEY 'b' VALUE b absent on null
       ) c2,
       json_object(
         KEY 'a' VALUE a,
         KEY 'b' VALUE b null on null
       ) c1
from   t;
```

Then the output is:

> ```
> C2               | C1              
> :--------------- | :---------------
> {"a":1,"b":null} | {"a":1,"b":null}
> {"a":2,"b":"bb"} | {"a":2,"b":"bb"}
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=182124888a9efe76d4920e8a700268d1)*

Comment: @LukasEder Just to add, it is not the first time I saw this pattern(i.e taking first/last occurence as execution template: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52533487/string-agg-not-behaving-as-expected)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda: I have seen it before, too, e.g. in HSQLDB or MariaDB, not yet in Oracle.

Comment: This is a bug, it's been filed (31013529, though it's not currently public)

Comment: Simple `+0` is typical and well-known workaround for such bugs (such type of bugs is pretty old)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/xtender/afa5ffc01753d9473afead56da4e557a

Answer (score 3):

you found a bug.
I have filed 
Bug 31013529 - TWO JSON_OBJECT WITH DIFFERENT ON NULL HANDLER RETURN WRONG RESULTS

We'll fix it asap and include it in the bundle patches.
Let us know if you need a one off patch

thanks
b

Comment: I installed oracle 19 a month ago but still see this issue. Could post what patch is needed ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug for me:

```
select 
  json_object(key 'a' value 1, key 'b' value null null on null)   c1
  ,(SELECT json_object(key 'a' value 1, key 'b' value null absent on null) FROM dual) c2
from dual
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+---------+
|        C1         |   C2    |
+-------------------+---------+
| {"a":1,"b":null}  | {"a":1} |
+-------------------+---------+
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=21ab639ded3f60d958780bc89a12ca3e)**

It is one of these strange occurences when wrapping with `(SELECT exp FROM dual)` changes the resultset (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52561721/5070879).

---

I guess it is some optimization mechanism("common subexpression elimination") that causes the exp is evaluated once taking the first/last occurence. If you change the key it is working fine:

```
select 
  json_object(key 'a' value 1, key 'b' value null null on null)   c1, 
  json_object(key 'a' value 1, key 'c' value null absent on null) c2
from dual;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a1e36bcfa03d775ae87b9cbc2bfae967)**

Answer (score 0):

[Lukasz's answer provides a viable workaround using a correlated subquery.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60621795/521799)

For the record, other functions are also affected, e.g. `JSON_ARRAYAGG`:

```sql
select
  json_arrayagg(a null on null) c1,
  json_arrayagg(a absent on null) c2
from (
  select 1 a from dual union all select null a from dual
) t;
```

Yields:

```
|C1        |C2        |
|----------|----------|
|[1]       |[1]       |
```

Whereas this workaround...

```java
select 
  cast(json_arrayagg((select a from dual) absent on null) as varchar2(10)) c2,
  cast(json_arrayagg((select a from dual) null on null) as varchar2(10)) c1
from (
  select 1 a from dual union all select null a from dual
) t;
```

Produces the correct result:

```
|C2        |C1        |
|----------|----------|
|[1]       |[1,null]  |
```

Comment: Simple `+0` is typical and well-known workaround for such bugs (such type of bugs is pretty old)

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov: That might work in ad-hoc cases, although 1) only with numbers or dates, not strings 2) only if it isn't added to each and every expression, or the same bug re-appears. My workaround seems more thorough, in this case.

Comment: 1) `||''` for strings :) *2) only if it isn't added to each and every expression, or the same bug re-appears.* nope, you need just 1 minimum difference with other function calls. Maybe your workaround more thorough, but it also much harder - additional cpu load, latches, etc for each call

Comment: + returning instead of cast: `json_arrayagg((select a from dual) absent on null returning varchar2(10))` https://gist.github.com/xtender/e8e686cbfad1bae72467ed440b5e0253

Answer (score -1):

you have a small change in order to get the values:

```
select 
 json_object(key 'a' value 1, key 'b' value null )   c1, 
 json_object(key 'a' value 1 ) c2
from dual;
```

The result is
C1:                 C2:
{"a":1,"b":null}    {"a":1}